# Amazon S3 signed url for arbitrary filename

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How might I set up a signed url for a GET request when that file hasn't been uploaded yet and I don't know the filename?

The reason this is happening is because I'm letting people upload arbitrary files to my s3 bucket with a pre-signed POST url. But I want to let the same people that are uploading, download their file without needing to hit my server again to generate the url.

Comment: What if two people choose the same arbitrary filename?

Comment: That won't happen in my case because you can only upload one file into this key location.